# Jacoco's report not generate

Tags: maven, jacoco

In my pom.xml

```
    <profile>
            <id>coverage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx4096m ${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
<!--                            Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx4096m ${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
<!--                            Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
<!--                            Let's put failsafe reports with surefire to have access to tests failures/success reports in sonar -->
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                        <executions>
<!--                            Prepares a variable, jacoco.agent.ut.arg, that contains the info to be passed to the JVM hosting the code being tested. -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.ut.arg</propertyName>
                                    <append>true</append>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
<!--                            Prepares a variable, jacoco.agent.it.arg, that contains the info to be passed to the JVM hosting the code being tested. -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-it-agent</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
                                    <append>true</append>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

Run

```
mvn clean verify
```

But in **target** folder not exist jacoco's coverage report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your profile is not activated by default, you need to specify `-Pcoverage` to your maven command to run this profile.

```
mvn clean verify -Pcoverage
```

You can also activate your `coverage` profile by adding the following to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<profile>
   <id>coverage</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <!-- Rest of the Profile build configuration -->
</profile>
```